# Simplifying expressions with dot or non-commutative product (without the help of NCAlgebra)

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, vector, vector-calculus, dot

I have two expressions (with dot and non-commutative product):

$f=J^T.x+J.x$

$g=J^T**x+J**x$

I want to simplify them and get the following expressions:

$f=(J^T+J).x$

$g=(J^T+J)**x$

In an attempt to solve this problem, I used some tricks from: [Symbolic Tensors](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SymbolicTensors.html)

```
$Assumptions = {x \[Element] Arrays[{3, 1}, Reals], J \[Element] Matrices[{3, 3}, Reals]};

expr = Transpose[J].x + J.x // TensorReduce
```

But the expression doesn't change. What needs to be done so that Mathematica can simplify expressions with scalar and non-commutative products?

**Some EDIT:**

```
Clear["Derivative"]; ClearAll["Global`*"];

Unprotect[Dot, Plus];

(*Dot rules*)
Dot[A_, x_] + Dot[B_, x_] := Dot[A + B, x];
Protect[Dot, Plus];

(***)

J.x + Transpose[J].x // TraditionalForm;

Clear["Derivative"]; ClearAll["Global`*"];

Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply, Plus];

(*NonCommutativeMultiply rules*)
NonCommutativeMultiply[A_, x_] + NonCommutativeMultiply[B_, x_] := 
  NonCommutativeMultiply[A + B, x];
Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply, Plus];

(***)

J ** x + Transpose[J] ** x // TraditionalForm;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
f = Transpose[J] . x + J . x
f /. c1_ . x + c2_ . x -> (c1 + c2) . x

(* J + Transpose[J]) . x *)
```

Note: take care to put a space between "*" and "." because "*." represents an argument that can be omitted and the above does not work:

```
f /. c1_. x + c2_. x -> (c1 + c2) . x
(* J . x + Transpose[J] . x *)
```

Comment: Hi Daniel! Thank you for your answer! Literally an hour ago I was visited by a similar thought, only I implemented it in the form of a general rule. Check out my edit. Your version is simpler and more compact. Let each user who reads the topic choose the option that is convenient for him.

Comment: In general, I was interested in the following subtlety in this problem. Let's say we have a very complex multi-component vector-matrix expression. There is a problem in the priority of simplification options created by a set of simplification rules and their possible contradictions, as well as the search for an optimal simplified variant. But these are just thoughts...

Comment: Your solution is also o.k. Priority problems may be solved by forceing an order on rules like e.g.:   ... /. ruleset1 /. ruleset2 ... Or maybe you need ReplaceRepeated : "//."